# How to access a variable in an object from a member object's function

Tags: c++

Ok, I have a class:

```
class class1
{
public:
     class2 object2;
     int a;
};
```

where:

```
class class2
{
public:
    void function2();
};
```

Basically, I need function2 in object2 to be able to access "a." How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: If you mean without modifying `function2` signature, then you can't do it. Members variables don't _know_ who owns them.

Comment: why does it need to access the data? Either put `a` in `class2` or give `class1` the behaviour you're trying to implement on `class2`.

Comment: I think Peter is right... I think my implementation was poor. Lemme try to redo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class class2
 {
  public:
        void Function2(class1& c1)
        {
          c1.a;
        }
  }
```

simple.

Comment: I ended up going a different route and just changing my code; this was a result of my lack of understanding of c++. Thanks for the response though.